# Is has_many still necessary when has_many through exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have what I feel like is a super simple question, but I can't find an answer anywhere!

**Question:**

If I previously had a has_many relationship like this: `has_many :wikis`, do I keep this relationship if later on I create a has_many through relationship like the following?

```
has_many :collaborators
has_many :wikis, through: :collaborators
```

This is all in my User model.

**Background:**

In my rails app, I have a User model and a Wiki model. I just gave users the ability to collaborate on private wikis so I migrated a Collaborator model and then came the step to create the has_many through relationships. I wasn't sure if I still needed `has_many :wikis` after putting `has_many :wikis, through: :collaborators`.

The reason I am confused is because Users should **still** be able to create wikis without collaborators and I'm not sure how the `has_many through` relationship works under the hood.

*Originally* I had only User and Wiki with a one-to-many relationship.

```
# User model
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...    
  has_many :wikis # should I delete this?
  has_many :collaborators
  has_many :wikis, through: :collaborators
  ...
end

# Collaborator model
class Collaborator < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wiki
end

# Wiki model
class Wiki < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :collaborators, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :collaborators
  ...
end
```

Comment: I would add two different relations, `has_many :created_wikis` and `has_many :collaborated_wikis`. Also, for better maintenance the user who creates wiki should be added as collaborator while creating wiki. Hence, the user can know which wikis he created and which wikis he can contribute to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is has_many still necessary when has_many through exists?

`has_many` not necessary when presence `has_many through` like your model

```
has_many :wikis # should I delete this?
has_many :collaborators
has_many :wikis, through: :collaborators
```

> should I delete this?

Yes, you can delete this one, you don't need this as the same `belongs_to`

From [The `has_many` Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)

> A has_many association indicates a one-to-many connection with another model. You'll often find this association on the "other side" of a belongs_to association. This association indicates that each instance of the model has zero or more instances of another model. For example, in an application containing authors and books, the author model could be declared like this:
>
> [image]

From [The `has_many :through` Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

> A `has_many :through` association is often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model. This association indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third model. For example, consider a medical practice where patients make appointments to see physicians. The relevant association declarations could look like this:
>
> ```rb
> class Physician < ApplicationRecord
>     has_many :appointments
>     has_many :patients, through: :appointments
>     end
>     
>     class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
>     belongs_to :physician
>     belongs_to :patient
>     end
>     
>     class Patient < ApplicationRecord
>     has_many :appointments
>     has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
>     end
> ```
>
> [image]

You can work with only `has_many` association without `has_many :through`, but this is one-to-many, this not many-to-many

- The `has_many` Association (without `has_many :through`) is one-to-many connection with another model
- The `has_many :through` Association is up a many-to-many connection with another model

**Update**

Look, one physician may have many patients, on the other hand, one patient may have many physicians if you use `has_many` association without through for patient then this called `one-to-many` association, that means one physician has many patients, on the other hand, one patient belongs to one physician, and now association looks like this

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :patients
end
 
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
end
```

**Update 2**

The `has_many` through the standard format your models after edited

```
# User model
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...    
  has_many :collaborators
  has_many :wikis, through: :collaborators
  ...
end

# Collaborator model
class Collaborator < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wiki
end

# Wiki model
class Wiki < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :collaborators, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :collaborators
  ...
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I read the docs but I still don't completely understand. So you're saying the many-to-many connection makes the one-to-many connection redundant?

Comment: Using the diagram above, should I include a `has_many` AND `has_many through` if I want a physician-patient relationship without appointments?

Comment: No, you don't need `has_many through` when a relationship between one-to-many, see the **Update** section to the answer @DamianRivas

Comment: You misunderstand me. I perfectly understand belongs_to and has_many. I just created collaborators and now want to implement has_many through. I'll just remove the original has_many and keep an eye out for errors.

Comment: No, I don't you need index for the parent like on the `wikis` table you need a `foreign_key`. for this, you need completely follow this topic http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association one-to-many

Comment: OK, well if you are not helped with my answer please let me know, I will remove the answer and any expert person will help you

Comment: I'm just confused because you're saying I don't need `has_many through` and that's not what I'm asking. it sounds like you're ignoring my Collaborator model that I'm trying to implement with `has_many through`. I updated my question and hopefully it clarifies what I am asking.

Comment: OK. I understood, see the **Update 2** on my answer, you can delete this `has_many :wikis # should I delete this?` from `user` and `belongs_to :user` from `Wiki` model

Comment: I appreciate your time! I'm new to Rails so sorry if I was unclear at first.

Comment: When quoting text from elsewhere, you must make it clear (using [quote formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes)) which parts of your answer are quoted, and from where. Just putting a link to the original source somewhere in the post does **not** count as attribution. Doing so is still implicitly passing off the content as original by not clearly indicating that it's from elsewhere. We encourage you to read [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321326) for more information.